# how to create macro to get multiple value?

Tags: excel, vba

i am beginner in excel vba i have huge list where the first name and last name in one column without any space or symbol and some name are in capital alphabet and some have no capital alphabet and they are the same column what would be the popossible macro to make space batween them...or any possible way....

thanks in advance....

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can't really help with VBA code if we can't see the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not reliable but will get you there with simple names. Select the range of names and run the macro.

```
Sub InsertSpacesInNames()
Dim pos As Long: pos = 0
Dim uc As Long: uc = 0
For Each cell In Selection
For i = 1 To Len(cell.Value)
If Asc((Mid(cell.Value, i, 1))) >= 65 And Asc((Mid(cell.Value, i, 1))) <= 90 Then
uc = uc + 1
pos = i
End If
Next i
If uc = 2 Then
cell.Value = Mid(cell.Value, 1, pos - 1) & " " & Mid(cell.Value, pos, Len(cell.Value))
End If
uc = 0
pos = 0
Next
End Sub
```

My output:

[image]

**This macro will work fine if and only if**:

1. you use it with simple names (no compound names like *Jean-PierreLeCosteau* which's desired output is *Jean-Pierre LeCosteau*)
2. the full name has two capital letters only.

Comment: Your code is running perfectly when first name and last name start with capital letter...but is there any other way when entire name start with capital alphabet and entire name has no capital alphabet....really appreciate your help thankyou...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the first name then simple example using formulas:

```
      A               B
 1    AmandaWinslet   = "Amanda" & " " & RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - LEN("Amanda"))) // result is Amanda Winslet
```

The VBA way of doing this would be:

```
Sub AddSpace()
    Range("A1") = "Amanda" & " " & VBA.Right$(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - Len("Amanda"))
End Sub
```

You will need to loop over the list in VBA and make `FirstName` a variable. Your post assumes you have the first name from somewhere